# 'Require' won't work on Index.js for my xampp server

Tags: javascript, websocket, xampp

I wanna start off by saying, I am a complete beginner, so I may have difficulty understanding any answers / terms you may mention.

I'm currently trying to make a web server using 'xampp' from following these youtube tutorials: https://youtu.be/XhLAB1wwzNk
I'm trying to require the 'ws' node module on an Index.js file. I'm given an error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at Index.js:1`
I'm not sure how I can get the require module working on my web server.

I've tried installing 'require' by running `npm i require` and I've also ran `npm init` to see if it'd do anything. Any help would be appreciated greatly

Comment: This is confusing because `xampp` is for php server and `node` is for javascript server. You normally wouldn't use both

Comment: Can you show us some code, maybe you have some syntax errors?

Comment: There is no code, I just have ```const ws = require('ws')```
I am getting the error: ```Uncaught refferencerror at line 1, require is not defined```
Would I be able to host a web server with node instead? Or can I have node modules on my php server? I also need to be able to use a data-base of some sort so that is why im trying to work with php

Comment: node has all the same database capabilities as php

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way around this, The problem I think was the fact that I was running a php server as oppose to a node.js server as @charlietfl said. So I went and set up a web socket server running off node instead of xampp. It works fine locally.

If anyone has any better suggestions, please feel free to post them.